# Probability of average times called being inside an interval

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, parameter-estimation

Assume that when a man calls a restaurant to order some food, his call has a probability $0.2$ of reaching through. Every attempt is independent and we can assume that the restaurant is open every day.

What is the probability that over the course of $30$ days, the man on average has to call more than $3$ times (call going through on the last one), every day?

I initially tried setting this up as a binomial distribution but with no luck, as I don't see how to deal with the average in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Model the number of calls until, and including, the first success as a Geometric RV and the number of days where one has to call more than 3 times to get through as Binomial as follows:

Each day the man calls the restaurant until they answer, which occurs with probability $p=0.2$, each call being independent of one another. Let $W$ be the number of the call that is finally answered. Then $W\sim Geo(p,\mathbb{N})$, that is $P(W=k)=q^{k-1}p$, where $q=1-p=0.8$. So, for example, the probability they answer on the first call is $P(W=1)=p=0.2$, and getting through in at most $k$ calls is given by the CDF, $P(W \leq k )=1-q^k$. Therefore, $P(W>3)=q^3$.

Now, if we repeat this for 30 days, assuming the calls for each day are independent of the previous days, we can model the number of days where it takes more than 3 calls to get through as a binomial RV, $Y\sim B(n,p^*)$, where $n=30$ and $p^*=P(W>3)$. You then are seeking to calculate $P(Y=30)$, the probability that every day the man must call more than 3 times to get through, which comes out to $P(Y=30)=1.89713759\cdot 10^{-9}$

The number of days the man must call more than 3 times to get through, on average is given by $E(Y)=np^*=30\cdot(0.8)^3=15.36$

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should be to find probability that on 90 calls there will be less than 30 answers. There are some approximations on [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) to do that. Have fun!

Comment: If I set number of trials to 90 and number of successes $30$, with probability on a single success being $0.2$ I get $P(X < 30) = 0.998$ (rounded to $3$ decimals, because the task asks me to do so). The actual answer is 0.997. I guess I initially completely overlooked this, because it seems ridicilous that he on average is almost guaranteed to have to call more than $3$ times every single day, but given the chance of a call going through being $0.2$, I guess it's not so weird after all.

Comment: If I try to convert this binomial distribution to a standard normal distribution, I get $\mu = np =18$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = 3.795$. If I now use $Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ I get $Z = 3.16$, and $P(Z<3.16) = 0$ which doesn't make sense. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe you can't approximate it with normal distribution for these values (at least not too accurately). Anyway probability of 0.998 sounds to me very reasonable, since you expect to have 5 calls until success per day.